# A problem related to cyclic group (group theory )

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Which of the following is false?
>
> 1. Any abelian group of order 27 is cyclic.
> 2. Any abelian group of order 14 is cyclic.
> 3. Any abelian group of order 21 is cyclic.
> 4. Any abelian group of order 30 is cyclic.

If we take $G=\mathbb{Z_3\times Z_3\times Z_3}$, then (1) is false.

I know if order$(G)=pq$,where $p,q$ are primes with  $p< q$
and $p$ divides $(q-1)$,then there is a unique non-abelian group of order $pq$. But I am not sure about other options. Are these true? Why?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Do you know the classification of finite abelian groups?

Then: Under what conditions is the group $\mathbb{Z}/n_1\mathbb{Z}\times . . . \times \mathbb{Z}/n_k\mathbb{Z}$ cyclic?

Answer (score 0):

Let $G$ be a finite group $G$ with identity $1.$ Let $|G|$ denote the number of members of $G$. For $x\in G$ let $[x]$ be the least positive integer $n$ for which $x^n=1.$  Then... (1)...$\forall x\in G ([x]$is a divisor of $|G|).$...(2)...$\forall x\in G \forall n\in Z^+(n|[x]\implies [x^n]=[x]/n.$...(3)...If $G$ is Abelian then $\forall x,y\in G (\gcd ([x],[y])=1\implies [x y]=[x][y]). $..... Suppose $G$ is Abelian and $|G|$ is the product of two distinct primes. To show that $G$ is cyclic, pick any $x\in G\backslash \{1\}. $ If $[x]=|G|$ then we are done. If $[x]\ne |G|$ then by (1), $[x]=p$ and $|G|=p q$ where $p,q$ are distinct primes. Since $G$ is Abelian. the subgroup $H=\{x^n :0\leq n<p\}$ is normal in $G. $ Hence $G/H=\{yH :y\in G\}$ is a group with $|G/H|=|G|/|H|=q. $ But since $q$ is prime, $G/H$ is cyclic.So for some $y\in G\backslash H$ we have $G/H=\{(yH)^j :0\leq j<q\}=\{y^j H :0\leq j<q\}.$ (This equality holds as $H$ is normal in $G$) .We can prove that $q|[y]$ by contradiction: If not, there are integers $c,d$ with $c q+d[y]=1$, but  $y^q H=H=y^{[y]}H$, giving  $y H=y^{c q}y^{d[y]}H=H$, which implies $y\in H$, which is false.....Finally let $ y'=y^{[y]/q}.$  We have $[y']=[y]/([y]/q)=q$ by (2) so $[x y']=p q=|G|$ by (3). So $G$ is cyclic.... Addendum. To prove (3) first prove that $\forall x \forall n>0 (x^n=1\implies [x]|n)$ .Now if $\gcd ([x],[y]=1)$ and $A=[x y]$ then $1=(x y)^{A[y]}=x^{A[y]}\implies [x]|A[y]\implies [x]|A. $ Interchanging $x$ and $y$ we get $[y]|A$ also. So $ [x][y]|A. $ But $A|[x y]$ by (2) because $(x y)^{[x][y]}=1.$